# Why JAXB Moxy throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: xml, scala, jaxb, moxy

When using Moxy as the JAXB Implementation,
the following class leads to an exception:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="fraPage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
case class FraPage(@ScalaXmlTypeAdapter(value=classOf[FraSeqAdapter]) @ScalaXmlElementWrapper(name="fras") data:Seq[Fra],@XmlTransient id: FraPageId, @ScalaXmlElement header:FraPageHeader) extends PageWithId[FraPageId]{


  private def this()= this(null,null,null)
  lazy val isEmpty = data.isEmpty



}


Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 0
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
    at com.gottex.gottware.services.Dummy$.main(Dummy.scala:16)
    at com.gottex.gottware.services.Dummy.main(Dummy.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateDirectCollectionMapping(MappingsGenerator.java:2004)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMapping(MappingsGenerator.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMappings(MappingsGenerator.java:2265)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateMappings(MappingsGenerator.java:2225)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateProject(MappingsGenerator.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.generateProject(Generator.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:913)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:905)
    ... 20 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is happening and why? I am using JDK 1.6.0.25 with Moxy version 2.4.0

Comment: Can you please list the versions of the components being used? The best way to figure it out is to drill down into the sources, but without knowing the version, line 2004 doesn't say much

Comment: Also, I assume this bug is not related: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331144 but worth checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

This appears to be a MOXy bug.  There is a method called `hasActualTypeArguments()` in the `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.reflection.JavaClassImpl` class that is returning a false positive.  You can track our progress on this issue using the following bug:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/393809